# vertically align text next to an image with CSS issue

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've been following every tip that I've found in the web but... I haven't make it work :(

this is a part of my css:

```
#content-container {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    background: #fff url(../images/asideBkg.gif) repeat-y 100% 0; /*Aside background image*/
}

#content {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    display: inline;
}

#content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}

#content p {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: left;
}

#content h2 { margin: 0; }

#aside {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    display: inline;    
}

#aside h3 { margin: 0; }
```

I have a Master Page and my content place holder is just the content div (not the aside), now the html is us follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="content">
    <h3>
        Contact us
    </h3>
    <hr />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>      
    <img src="images/mail32x32.png" alt="Mail" />    
    <p>
        Drop us an email at: <a href="mailto:#@#">#@#</a>
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <img src="images/phones32x32.png" alt="Phone" />
    <p>
        or give us a call at: <span style="color: #383;">###</span>
    </p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

the above is my original code, in which both images (mail and phone) are top aligned with the text, and I need them middle aligned.

I've tried `<img src="images/mail32x32.png" alt="Mail" style="vertical-align:middle;" />` but no luck. I thought could be something with the parent div, so I create a new one, same result.

Could someone look into the code and check what is wrong?

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but styles use `:` instead of `=` so you'd want `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped that. It is a : not a =

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how you want this page to look, but the easiest way by far is to use tables, where you can just use the valign attribute.  If your layout is very simple, thats what i would suggest.

Comment: What are you seeing that I'm not. The <p>'s are aligned fairly well to the middle currently. Will something else be added to this page to make their position shift? Or do you actually want them horizontally aligned?

Comment: I have all my page in css, I would'nt like to use tables to achieve that.

Comment: It must be something with the parent div that I'm not seeing, because I did some tests in another webpage from scratch, and it works: <img style="width:32px;height:32px;vertical-align:middle;" src="images/mail32x32.png" alt="" /> 
        <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">Testing text...</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Your margin was setting an all around margin, pushing your images down. I set the top and bottom margin's to 0 so your image would stay in the middle.

```
div#content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/vA7G4/) if you want to check it out.

Comment: hey it works for me just with this: #content img {
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 5px 3px 5px; 
} pushing the bottom unit, Thanks!!